# Definition of eigenvalues in PCA

Tags: pca, eigenvalues

I've been reading two (peer reviewed) papers that use Principal Component Analysis to solve a problem I'm interested in, they both state they find the eigenvalues for the correlation matrix using the equation

$$ | \lambda I - A| = 0. $$

When I've read around PCA and eigenvalue decomposition, the appropriate equation seems to be defined as

$$ |  A - \lambda I | = 0. $$

Could anyone explain to me why there might be a difference, and what the impact of this may be?

Comment: An equation $f(x) =0$ has the same roots as $-f(x)=0$.

Comment: Addition/subtraction of matrices is commutative (independent of the order of the matrices, of course with adapting of the sign in case of subtraction). After that, if the determinant $\det(C)=0$ then is also $ \det(-C)=-0=0$

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks. It's been a while since I've had to do anything outside of adding and subtracting!

Comment: @Gottfried $\det(-C) = \det(C)$ when the dimensions of $C$ are even--but your argument still holds.